# How do I create localized resources in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, localization, resources, translation, culture

I'm trying to add culture specific translations for the strings in my Resources.resx file and can't find anywhere to do this in visual studios.

Comment: I think this largely depends on the type of project you created in your Visual Studio solution, and therefore which programming framework is running that project (WinForms, ASP.NET WebForms, ASP.NET MVC, etc). Which framework or type of project have you created?

Comment: For my particular problem I was having, I was working with a .NET Framework 4 Class Library.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new resource file with an additional suffix that matches the culture string you're looking for.

For example, if you'd like to have translations associated with the neutral French culture ("fr") then create a resource file named Resources.fr.resx with your translations in it.